# Compare contents of Entry widget every time a key is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have here a code snippet from Python 2.7 and Tkinter:

I am trying to compare the contents of two Entry widgets every time I am typing a character in one of those two Entry widgets.

```
class MainApp():

def __init__(self, master):
    """Constructor"""

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.bind("<Key>", self.key)
    frame.pack()

    ...

    self.instruction = Label(frame,
            text="Press 'Show new word', then start typing the word",
            wraplength=250)
    self.instruction.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    self.word = StringVar()

    self.new_word = Entry(frame, justify=CENTER,
            textvariable=self.word, bg="green", fg="yellow",
            font="Arial 24 bold", relief=FLAT)
    self.new_word.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    self.input_word = Entry(frame, font="Monospace 12")
    self.input_word.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    self.create_word = Button(frame, text="New word (press Enter)",
            command=self.generate_word)
    self.create_word.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    self.input_word.focus_set()

def generate_word(self):
    """New word generator"""

    ...


def key(self, event):
    """Enter char in to input_word"""

    ...
    self.check()

def check(self):
    """Checks your entered char"""

    a = self.new_word.get()
    b = self.input_word.get()

    if a != b:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

With this code the Tkinter event handler cannot detect that I am typing new characters or it won't even run the method to compare the Entry widgets.

I can't seem to figure out the solution just yet but I am still trying to do so.

Comment: Why are you binding on the frame? Add the bindings to the entry widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley it works! Thanks!